# Inheritance in JPA- How to access subclass values?

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa

I have following classes

```
class A {
private int field1;
private int field2;
private int field3;
private int field4;
}


Class B extends A {

private int field3;
private int field4;
```

}

```
 Class C extends A {
  private int field3;
  private int field4;
  }
```

Based on Class A's "field1" value, I need to access either Class B fields or Class C fields and set the values of parent fields.

I am using orm mapping xml for JPA. Class A table and their subclasses maps to different tables therefore I have specified Inheritance Strategy as JOINED.

There are fields in Class A which I need to convert on POST-LOAD and also I need to set A."field3" and A."field4" values therefore I have specified entity listners.

JPA query creates join between these Class A, B, C's three tables and retreive values from all three classes.

But On the post-load I am getting only parent class A.

My question is: how to access Class B and Class C field values?? so that I can set parent field values.

Comment: Are you expecting to get one entity back or several? I fail to see how an instance of A could contain the data from the tables for classes B and/or C. Also, all fields in A are declared private, so there is no (easy) way for B and C to access them. A cannot access B and C values internally.

Comment: I am expecting only one entity A back and send it to other component.The query generated from JPA does retreive all values from B and C also. so I need to get the value of B or C then set A. In the entity listener post load method I need to get B and C..But I dont know how to get B and C.

Comment: So you get instances of B and C as well?

Comment: that's the question how to get instances of B and C?

Comment: You have posted no code, so it's hard to see what you are actually doing. I seem to remember a JPA way of mapping a result set to several different entities (ie different types). Otherwise, you could use the @SecondaryTable annotation and read all the data you want and then do what you want.

Comment: Erik, same field exists in A, B and C. @SecondaryTable may work but I need to create multiple (same type)fields in class A and map it to different table. So not a good suggestion. In the entity-listner post load method I need to get the instance of B and C. I am assuming through JPA query, all the fields are B and C are loaded. so the question is how to get instance of B and C in Class A's entity-listener post-load method?

Comment: Since you are not posting code nor your persistence.xml it is hard to come up with good suggestions. I'm flailing in the dark, as it were. Your use case too seems a bit strange to express it mildly. The more information you provide, the easier is it for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

From your question :

> JPA query creates join between these Class A, B, C's three tables and retreive values from all three classes.

so create three different classes A, B and C, do not inherit as you provided. Retrieve three tables into three objects A, B and C using join.
Now you have three objects a,b and c. Now check value of a.field1 and access your object b or c.

Comment: I have set the entity-listener post-load method on Class A. So in the post-load method I am checking the instance. It gives instance of A, but not B or C. so I am not able to understand how to get B and C (which I am assuming are loaded)

Comment: can you please put more comment on constructor call hierarchy in inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: I am sorry I misguided you, as I considered Class B extends A and C extends B. I will edit my answer

Comment: If I create three separate classes and join it. it means I need to add extra fields in the class A. It may work but class A has been provided by the business so I can not make changes to it. Therefore I have created two sub classes which are not provided by the business. Class B  & C are created by myself to resolve business logic as detailed initially

Answer (score 0):

Make A abstract. Then you can do *instance of* to know which type it is and cast it to that type:

```
if (a instance of B) {
      B b = (B) a;
} else if (a instance of C) {
      C c = (C) a;
}
```

Comment: Class A has other fields as well which are not inherited by B and C. So making class A abstract may not work. Also class A has been provided by the business so I can not make changes to it.

Comment: By definition, all the fields are inherited... That is what inheritance is about. If you can not change class A, then I would suggest you to create two methods, one to retrieve B objects and another to retrieve C objects.